# Get Meta Data from PDF using PDFsharp

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

How do I get meta data from PDF using PDFsharp. Refer to the image.
I want to extract 'Document Restrictions Summary'

```
private static void Method1(string strPDFAddress)
        {
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(strPDFAddress);

            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("File: {0}", strPDFAddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Author: {0}", pdfDoc.Info.Author);
            Console.WriteLine("CreationDate: {0}", pdfDoc.Info.CreationDate);
            Console.WriteLine("Creator: {0}", pdfDoc.Info.Creator);
            Console.WriteLine("Keywords: {0}", pdfDoc.Info.Keywords);

            PdfDocumentSettings pdfDocSettings = pdfDoc.Settings;
            Console.WriteLine(pdfDocSettings.ToString());

            PdfSecuritySettings pdfSecuritySettings = pdfDoc.SecuritySettings;
            Console.WriteLine(pdfSecuritySettings.PermitExtractContent);

            //PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced.PdfFormXObject xObj = 

            PdfDictionary.DictionaryElements pdfDictionaryElements = pdfDoc.Info.Elements;
            Console.WriteLine(pdfDictionaryElements.ToString());
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Hope it works.

`PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("HelloWorldNoMetadata.pdf");`

`string s = reader.Info["Author"];`

Comment: No, this will not get what I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can set these document restrictions with the `PdfSecuritySettings` class.

See this sample:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/ProtectDocument-sample.ashx

I'm not sure but I would expect that this structure will also be filled when opening a PDF document.

Comment: It is returning 'true' for all the boolean values.
After executing the code it is corrupting the pdf and I would not be able to open the pdf.

Comment: @Kirk Does this happen with all PDF files or only with some?